# Does load testing affect local pc CPU usage and physical memory?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am doing load testing of one website. Website is hosted on another server i.e Godaddy.

I have installed Jmeter on my local machine and configured necessary things to start load testing. When I increase no. of users through Jmeter and check my pc CPU usage , it shows high up and down and also, physical memory gets full during heavy load.

My question is I am putting load on server then why it affects local pc CPU usage and memory? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running the JMeter on your local machine. The load on your local machine comes from creating the requests to be sent to the server and handling the responses from the server.

You may want to check for example [this blog post](https://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) for performance tuning tips, such as running real load tests in non-gui mode.

Comment: I see , But result I am getting while running from local pc is accurate result?

Comment: I your local machine resources are not enough, for example if it starts swapping because there is not enough memory, then the results will not be accurate.

Comment: Okay , So what is best way? Should I install jmeter on server? where site is hosted?

Comment: You can probably run it ok on the local machine. Did you check the performance tuning things? Those should help so that you could reliably use you local machine also.

Comment: Yep I am checking that blog post..

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you can use siege tool for a simple http/https load testing of your website.

More details about Siege tool is here: https://www.joedog.org/siege-home/.

You can trigger the siege request from your local machine without impacting its cpu/memory usage.